# How iPhone Contact app detect user has number linked to WhatsApp?

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts

I just want to know how iPhone app is able to detect that mobile number is registered with WhatsApp, IMO, JioChat like in screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the iPhone app does not detect that. WhatsApp probably checks your contacts for available contacts, then adds a value to the user in `Contacts.framework`.

Comment: Can you tell me, how we can add value in Contacts.framework